# C# : How to check length of list in Session

Tags: c#

I want to check length of list in session. How to do that?

For example :

```
Session["AnswerDetail"] = new List<T_Answer_Detail>();

if(Session["AnswerDetail"].Length!=5)
{
 lblMessage.Text = "Your answer is complete";
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `(Session["AnswerDetail"] as List<T_Answer_Detail>).Count`

Comment: ((List<T>)Session["X"]).Count <== C#

Answer (score 0):

Try a [safe cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488006.aspx), to make sure you have the list on the session, and heck the `Lenght` property:

```
var anserDetails = Session["AnswerDetail"] as List<AnswerDetail>;

if(anserDetails != null && anserDetails.Length != 5)
{
   lblMessage.Text = "Your answer is complete";
}
```

Not sure about eh type of your list, if it is an array, a generic list, or any other type of collections. The `AnswerDetail` on the code is just an sample.